# Google Cloud Messaging Notification vs Data

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I was reading the GCM documentation about the difference between **notification** type and **data** type when you want to send a message to a mobile device.

They say that **notification** type is always collapsed but for me its not clear what it means exactly?

Does it mean that if i send two or more notification (before the user is able to open the previous one) only the last one will be visible?

Answer (score 2):

> Collapsible or Non-Collapsible

The push messages can be either collapsible or non-collapsible. “Collapsible” means that the most recent message overwrites any previous ones queued for sending. A typical example of collapsible messaging is a live game score. In case previous score updates haven’t reached their destination yet, the Android clients would only get the latest one. This happens however on a best effort basis: the order in which messages get sent in GCM is not guaranteed, so in some cases the “latest” message may not be actually the most recent one.

**Notification:** Set notification payload. May have optional data payload. Always collapsible.

**Data:** Set data payload only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.